# how add storyboard to my framework and appear in library pod as resources when make pod install for some project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Pod Spec, how can I set a storyboard to my framework?

I tried many approaches, but, the main problem is that when I make a pod install, the storyboard does not appear in my pod library.
I am trying to set the storyboard in the bundle, but, when I make a pod install of the bundle, it does not appear in pods.

```
s.resources = 'LocationPicker/Resources/LocationPicker.bundle' 
s.resources = 'LocationPicker/Resources/**/*.storyboard' 
s.resources = 'LocationPicker/Resources/Base/*.storyboard' 
s.resources = 'LocationPicker/Resources/Base.lproj/*.storyboard' 
strong text 
s.resource_bundle = { 'LocationPicker' => [ 
  'LocationPicker/Resources/**/*.{png,storyboard,lproj,xib,xcassets}' 
] }
```

Comment: s.resources = 'LocationPicker/Resources/LocationPicker.bundle'
s.resources = 'LocationPicker/Resources/**/*.storyboard'
s.resources = 'LocationPicker/Resources/Base/*.storyboard'
s.resources = 'LocationPicker/Resources/Base.lproj/*.storyboard'
**strong text**
s.resource_bundle = { 'LocationPicker' => [ 'LocationPicker/Resources/**/*.{png,storyboard,lproj,xib,xcassets}' ] }

Comment: Please don't add comments; [edit] your question instead. Code is unreadable in comments.